# Selecting duplicate records except the first and last duplicate with Select by expression in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, select-by-attribute, duplication, if-statement

I'd like to know how to select duplicate records except **the first and last one**, with the "Select by attribute/expression". On GIS SE I found a solution for selecting duplicates except the first one, with the below expression (on the picture is the **current solution I have that selects all but the first duplicate**):

```sql
CASE
    WHEN "PortClustersIDs3_CLUSTER_ID" IS NOT NULL
        THEN array_contains(
                array_remove_at(
                    array_agg($id, "PortClustersIDs3_CLUSTER_ID" ),
                    0),
                $id)
END
```

I would like to modify the above expression or write up a completely new expression for selecting all but the first ***as well as the last duplicate***. So in the below picture/example **I don't want the 20th row to be selected** and the 17th row already isn't.

[image]

---

After @MrXsquared’s answer, I still have a problem with my specific case. I need to use their expression inside a CASE statement (or maybe if statement?), because I need to filter out rows when the `"PortClustersIDs3_CLUSTER_ID"` feature is not `NULL`.

As you can see from the pictures I now added it works on the first occurrence of duplicates (see 2nd screenshot) but when a few rows after the `"PortClustersIDs3_CLUSTER_ID" IS NOT NULL` again the code provided does not work (see 3rd screenshot). I think it's a problem with my CASE statement because you probably should be building **new array for each set of rows where** "PortClustersIDs3_CLUSTER_ID" is not null?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you want if there's exactly two duplicates? Select neither?

Comment: As per the [help/behavior] please do not include chit chat like statements of appreciation within your posts.

Comment: Set a filter `"PortClustersIDs3_CLUSTER_ID" is not null`, no need for case

Answer (score 5):

You can use this with select by expression:

```
with_variable('arr',array_agg($id, "myfield"),
if($id in (@arr[0],@arr[-1]),false,true))
```

Or for older QGIS versions where index brackets are not supported and without the use of a variable its:

```
if($id in (array_first(array_agg($id, "myfield")),array_last(array_agg($id, "myfield"))),false,true)
```

Example result:

[image]

Comment: I edited the post as I am still facing a few problems, your help would be greatly appreciated!